# Help with the definition of a manifold with boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

In the definition of a manifold with boundary, we often work with the closed upper half-space $H^{n}=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\,|\, x^{n}\geq0\right\}$ 
 , and endow $H^{n}$
  with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
 , which we can call $\tau$
 . We then say that the boundary of $H^{n}$
  is given by $\partial H^{n}=H^{n}=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\,|\, x^{n}=0\right\}$ 
 . However, if we're working with the subspace topology, does this not imply that $interior\left(H^{n}\right)=H^{n}$
 , since $H^{n}$
  would itself be open in this topology? It then follows that $\partial H^{n}=\emptyset$
 , which doesn't make sense in our context. Are we instead using the $\partial H^{n}$
  from the original Euclidean topology and carrying that language over by some convention? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to involve topology in the definition of $\partial H^n$, you can just define it as a set ($\{x^n=0\}$). If you want to define it using topological terms (the notation and the intended use indicate that this is desired) it is in fact the boundary of $H^n$ with respect to the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*The boundary of a manifold* is, in any case, by definition, the image of that set in coordinate charts. Any properties of this set are to be derived from that definition.

Comment: Thomas, thanks a lot, it is much clearer now.